# Single-pass authentication with a block cipher that accepts a counter

Tags: authenticated-encryption

Suppose we have a tweakable block cipher ($E(K, T, X)$ and $D(K, T, X)$) that is used in a scheme where the tweak, either in whole or in part, is used as a counter to make each block encrypt to a distinct ciphertext. If we XOR all of the blocks together and then encrypt the result, do we have a secure tag?

Answer (score 3):

It is not secure if you use the $E(K, T, X)$ values as the exposed ciphertext; it is secure if you're using this scheme as a MAC (and use an independent scheme to encrypt).

If you send the $C_i = E(K, T_i, X_i)$ as the ciphertext (and send $E(K, 0, \bigoplus C_i)$ as the tag, then what the attacker could do is flip the same bit on two different $C_i$ values.  The resulting $\bigoplus C_i$ will remain the same, and so the tag would validate (and the decrypted plaintext would be incorrect).

On the other hand, if you keep all the $C_i$ values internal, then this system can be viewed as a Carter-Wegman MAC.  All you need to show is that $\bigoplus C_i$ is an [almost universal hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing) (which is fairly easy to do, assuming you get the message padding right), and the standard CW proofs apply.

Comment: Ah. I see why this scheme isn't used. Each ciphertext block needs to be transformed again with a keyed function before XORing them all together and encrypting the result. Is there a limit to the length of a message that can be authenticated securely under such a scheme and how does it compare to a chained MAC like HMAC or CBC-MAC?

Comment: @Melab: no, there wouldn't be any particular length limitations (at least until you hit the birthday bound); the CW argument above shows that $\bigoplus C_i$ remains universal up until then (and it probably is beyond that as well, i don't have an immediate proof of that)

Comment: Right, the birthday bound. That's what I was talking about. I didn't know if it applied to XOR MACs. I've seen claims that schemes like Bernstein's "protected counter sum" have beyond birthday bound security.

Comment: Are XOR MACs a variant of Carter-Wegman MACs?

Comment: Yes (actually, not a 'variant', rather a 'type of CW MAC'); however your MAC is different than what is commonly termed an "XOR MAC"

Comment: Does the protected counter sum scheme have birthday bound security?

Comment: The first two paragraphs of the third page of [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/852.pdf) seem to imply that it does.